# How to change datatype of each item in a list of tuples

Tags: python

I've generated something that looks like this:

```
list = [('94028', 'Evening', '2.23'), ('94028', 'Night', '1.16'), ('94028', 'Morning', '2.0'),....
```

I'd like to format this object so that Index 0 of each is a `str`, Index 1 of each is a `str`, and Index 2 is an `int` or a `float`.  And have that propagate down the whole object so that it turns into this:

```
list = [("94028", "Evening", 2.23), ("94028", "Night", 1.16), ("94028", "Morning", 2.0),....
```

How can I do this?

Tried:

```
for d in list:
  d[1] = int(d[1])
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** modify tuples. They are immutable. Best you can do is create a new tuple and assign it in place of an old one or just recreate the list with comprehension editing elements as necessary.

```
l = [('94028', 'Evening', '2.23'), ('94028', 'Night', '1.16'), ('94028', 'Morning', '2.0')]

l = [(el[0], el[1], float(el[2])) for el in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the tuples. But you can make new tuples and put them in their place:

```
for i, d in enumerate(list): 
    list[i] = (*d[:2], float(d[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original attempt used a loop to try to modify the existing tuples, which isn't possible because tuples are immutable. Instead, you need to create new list with the desired modifications.

```py
original_list = [('94028', 'Evening', '2.23'), ('94028', 'Night', '1.16'), ('94028', 'Morning', '2.0')]

formatted_list = []

for item in original_list:
    formatted_item = (item[0], item[1], float(item[2]))
    formatted_list.append(formatted_item)

print(formatted_list)
```